# Select Case w/Public Functions

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to enhance my VBA skills and efficiency with the code below.  It currently executes at about 20 minutes.  I just recently learned how to use public functions but this project is very robust and I haven't been able to make it more efficient.  I've cut off two *Case* requirements `{Auto - Sentra/Van Fleet ($) ; Other ($)}` to be able to fit the code with its public functions.  They repeat the same functionality expect the range input at the end of calling the functions changes.  I'm assuming dictionaries will be a good starting point but I'm having difficulty comprehending its functionality.

```
   Dim Wb1 As Workbook, Wb2 As Workbook
        Dim Wk4 As Worksheet, Wk5 As Worksheet, Wk7 As Worksheet
        Dim Wk1 As Worksheet
        Dim CCRg As Range, CLinkRg As Range
        Dim AllEntRg As Range, EntityOnlyRg As Range
        Dim TypeRg As Range, GLRg As Range, OpsRg As Range
        Dim FRow As Long, lRow As Long
        Dim InlandRg As Range
        Dim ATLNrg As Range, ATLErg As Range, ATLSrg As Range
        Dim CCCodeRow As Long, CCCodeCol As Long

Sub Maverick()

starttime = Now()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set Wb1 = Workbooks("SubModel Forecast_Other Admin v4.xlsm")
Set Wb2 = Workbooks("Feb15 PNL.xlsx")
Set Wk4 = Wb1.Sheets("ASSUMPTIONS")
Set Wk5 = Wb1.Sheets("Validation")
Set Wk7 = Wb1.Sheets("GL Mapping")
Set Wk1 = Wb2.Sheets("det")

With Wb1
    With Wk5
        Dim CCCol As Long, fRowCC As Long, lRowCC As Long
        CCCol = Wk5.Cells.Find("Cost Center", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
        fRowCC = Wk5.Cells.Find("Cost Center", lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(1, 0).Row
        lRowCC = Wk5.Cells.Find("Cost Center", lookat:=xlWhole).End(xlDown).Row
        Set CCRg = Wk5.Range(Wk5.Cells(fRowCC, CCCol), Wk5.Cells(lRowCC, CCCol))
        Set CLinkRg = Wk5.Range(Wk5.Cells(fRowCC, CCCol).Offset(0, -1), Wk5.Cells(lRowCC, CCCol).Offset(0, -1))
    End With

    With Wk7
        Dim MapGLCol As Long, MapfRow As Long, MaplRow As Long
        MapGLCol = Wk7.Cells.Find("GL", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
        MapfRow = Wk7.Cells.Find("GL", lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(1, 0).Row
        MaplRow = Wk7.Cells(Rows.Count, MapGLCol).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim MapGLRg As Range
        Set MapGLRg = Wk7.Range(Wk7.Cells(MapfRow, MapGLCol), Wk7.Cells(MapfRow, MapGLCol))
        Set TypeRg = Wk7.Range(Wk7.Cells(MapfRow, MapGLCol).Offset(0, -1), Wk7.Cells(MaplRow, MapGLCol).Offset(0, -1))
    End With

    With Wk4

        Wk4.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=2

        Dim dateRow As Long, fRow2 As Long, AssumCol As Long, lRow2 As Long
        dateRow = Wk4.Cells.Find("ACT", lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(1, 0).Row
        fRow2 = Wk4.Cells.Find("Global Assumptions", lookat:=xlWhole).Row
        AssumCol = Wk4.Cells.Find("Global Assumptions", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
        lRow2 = Wk4.Cells(Rows.Count, AssumCol).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim AssumptionRg As Range
        Set AssumptionRg = Wk4.Range(Wk4.Cells(fRow2, AssumCol), Wk4.Cells(lRow2, AssumCol))

    End With
End With

With Wb2
With Wk1

    Dim OpsCol As Long
    OpsCol = Wk1.Cells.Find("Property Manager", lookat:=xlWhole).Column

    Dim PropCodeCol As Long
    FRow = Wk1.Cells.Find("66990000", lookat:=xlPart).Offset(2, 0).Row
    lRow = Wk1.Cells.Find("66990000", lookat:=xlPart).End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0).Row
    PropCodeCol = Wk1.Cells.Find("Property Code", lookat:=xlWhole).Column
    Set OpsRg = Wk1.Range(Wk1.Cells(FRow, OpsCol), Wk1.Cells(lRow, OpsCol))
    Dim PropCodeRg As Range
    Set PropCodeRg = Wk1.Range(Wk1.Cells(FRow, PropCodeCol), Wk1.Cells(lRow, PropCodeCol))

    Dim GLRow As Long, BegGLCol As Long, EndGLCol As Long
    GLRow = Wk1.Cells.Find("66550000", lookat:=xlPart).Row
    BegGLCol = Wk1.Cells.Find("66550000", lookat:=xlPart).Column
    EndGLCol = Wk1.Cells.Find("66990000", lookat:=xlPart).Column

    Dim BadDebtCol As Long
    BadDebtCol = Wk1.Cells.Find("66550300", lookat:=xlPart).Column
    Dim BadDebtGLRg As Range
    Set BadDebtGLRg = Wk1.Range(Wk1.Cells(FRow, BadDebtCol), Wk1.Cells(lRow, BadDebtCol))

    Set GLRg = Wk1.Range(Wk1.Cells(GLRow, BegGLCol), Wk1.Cells(GLRow, EndGLCol))

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In OpsRg
      If cell = "" Then
          If AllEntRg Is Nothing Then
              Set AllEntRg = Wk1.Cells(cell.Row, PropCodeCol)
          Else
              Set AllEntRg = Union(AllEntRg, Wk1.Cells(cell.Row, PropCodeCol))
          End If
      End If
    Next cell
    Set cell = Nothing

    For Each cell In AllEntRg
      If CCRg.Find(cell.Value, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
          If EntityOnlyRg Is Nothing Then
              Set EntityOnlyRg = Wk1.Cells(cell.Row, PropCodeCol)
          Else
              Set EntityOnlyRg = Union(EntityOnlyRg, Wk1.Cells(cell.Row, PropCodeCol))
          End If
      End If
    Next cell
    Set cell = Nothing

    Dim EvictionRg As Range
    Set EvictionRg = CategoryGLRange("Evictions ($)")

    Dim CreditFeesRg As Range
    Set CreditFeesRg = CategoryGLRange("Credit Verification Fees ($)")

    Dim LegalCounselFeesRg As Range
    Set LegalCounselFeesRg = CategoryGLRange("Legal Counsel Fees ($)")

        Dim OfficeRentRg As Range
        Set OfficeRentRg = CategoryGLRange("Office - Rent ($)")

        Dim OfficeUtilitiesRg As Range
        Set OfficeUtilitiesRg = CategoryGLRange("Office - Utilities ($)")

        Dim OfficeOtherRg As Range
        Set OfficeOtherRg = CategoryGLRange("Office - Other ($)")

    Dim OfficeMgmtRg As Range
    Set OfficeMgmtRg = Application.Union(OfficeRentRg, OfficeUtilitiesRg, OfficeOtherRg)

    Dim AutoLeaseRg As Range
    Set AutoLeaseRg = CategoryGLRange("Auto - Sentra/Van Fleet ($)")

    Dim OtherRg As Range
    Set OtherRg = CategoryGLRange("Other ($)")

End With
End With

With Wb1
With Wk4

    Dim r As Range
    Dim isItem As Boolean
        For Each r In AssumptionRg
            Select Case r
                Case "Evictions ($)"
                    isItem = True

                    If r.End(xlUp) = "Tie-Out To Actuals" Or r.End(xlUp) = "Entity Level Assumptions" _
                    Or r.End(xlUp) = "Inland Empire" Or r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta East" _
                    Or r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta North" Or r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta South" Then

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Tie-Out To Actuals" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(EvictionRg)
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Entity Level Assumptions" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(EntityGLRg(AllEntRg, EvictionRg))
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Inland Empire" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), EvictionRg) _
                            + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "cahied"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "cahrvr"), EvictionRg))
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta East" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), EvictionRg) _
                            + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atlse"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atle"), EvictionRg))
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta North" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), EvictionRg) _
                            + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atlnw"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atln"), EvictionRg))
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta South" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), EvictionRg) _
                            + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atlsw"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atls"), EvictionRg))
                        End If

                    Else
                        Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), EvictionRg)
                    End If

                Case "Credit Verification Fees ($)"
                    isItem = True

                    If r.End(xlUp) = "Tie-Out To Actuals" Or r.End(xlUp) = "Entity Level Assumptions" _
                    Or r.End(xlUp) = "Inland Empire" Or r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta East" _
                    Or r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta North" Or r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta South" Then

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Tie-Out To Actuals" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(CreditFeesRg)
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Entity Level Assumptions" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(EntityGLRg(AllEntRg, CreditFeesRg))
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Inland Empire" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), CreditFeesRg) _
                            + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "cahied"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "cahrvr"), CreditFeesRg))
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta East" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), CreditFeesRg) _
                            + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atlse"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atle"), CreditFeesRg))
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta North" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), CreditFeesRg) _
                            + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atlnw"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atln"), CreditFeesRg))
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta South" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), CreditFeesRg) _
                            + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atlsw"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atls"), CreditFeesRg))
                        End If

                    Else
                        Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), CreditFeesRg)
                    End If


                Case "Legal Counsel Fees ($)"
                    isItem = True

                    If r.End(xlUp) = "Tie-Out To Actuals" Or r.End(xlUp) = "Entity Level Assumptions" _
                    Or r.End(xlUp) = "Inland Empire" Or r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta East" _
                    Or r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta North" Or r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta South" Then

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Tie-Out To Actuals" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(LegalCounselFeesRg)
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Entity Level Assumptions" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(EntityGLRg(AllEntRg, LegalCounselFeesRg))
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Inland Empire" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), LegalCounselFeesRg) _
                            + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "cahied"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "cahrvr"), LegalCounselFeesRg))
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta East" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), LegalCounselFeesRg) _
                            + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atlse"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atle"), LegalCounselFeesRg))
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta North" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), LegalCounselFeesRg) _
                            + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atlnw"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atln"), LegalCounselFeesRg))
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta South" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), LegalCounselFeesRg) _
                            + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atlsw"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atls"), LegalCounselFeesRg))
                        End If

                    Else
                        Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), LegalCounselFeesRg)
                    End If

                Case "Office - Prop Mgmt ($)"
                    isItem = True

                    If r.End(xlUp) = "Tie-Out To Actuals" Or r.End(xlUp) = "Entity Level Assumptions" _
                    Or r.End(xlUp) = "Inland Empire" Or r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta East" _
                    Or r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta North" Or r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta South" Then

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Tie-Out To Actuals" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(OfficeMgmtRg)
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Entity Level Assumptions" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(EntityGLRg(AllEntRg, OfficeMgmtRg))
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Inland Empire" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), OfficeMgmtRg) _
                            + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "cahied"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "cahrvr"), OfficeMgmtRg))
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta East" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), OfficeMgmtRg) _
                            + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atlse"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atle"), OfficeMgmtRg))
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta North" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), OfficeMgmtRg) _
                            + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atlnw"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atln"), OfficeMgmtRg))
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta South" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), OfficeMgmtRg) _
                            + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atlsw"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atls"), OfficeMgmtRg))
                        End If

                    Else
                        Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), OfficeMgmtRg)
                    End If

                Case "Office - Rent ($)"
                    isItem = True

                    If r.End(xlUp) = "Tie-Out To Actuals" Or r.End(xlUp) = "Entity Level Assumptions" _
                    Or r.End(xlUp) = "Inland Empire" Or r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta East" _
                    Or r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta North" Or r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta South" Then

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Tie-Out To Actuals" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(OfficeRentRg)
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Entity Level Assumptions" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(EntityGLRg(AllEntRg, OfficeRentRg))
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Inland Empire" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), OfficeRentRg) _
                            + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "cahied"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "cahrvr"), OfficeRentRg))
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta East" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), OfficeRentRg) _
                            + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atlse"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atle"), OfficeRentRg))
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta North" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), OfficeRentRg) _
                            + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atlnw"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atln"), OfficeRentRg))
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta South" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), OfficeRentRg) _
                            + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atlsw"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atls"), OfficeRentRg))
                        End If

                    Else
                        Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), OfficeRentRg)
                    End If

                Case "Office - Utilities ($)"
                    isItem = True

                    If r.End(xlUp) = "Tie-Out To Actuals" Or r.End(xlUp) = "Entity Level Assumptions" _
                    Or r.End(xlUp) = "Inland Empire" Or r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta East" _
                    Or r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta North" Or r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta South" Then

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Tie-Out To Actuals" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(OfficeUtilitiesRg)
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Entity Level Assumptions" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(EntityGLRg(AllEntRg, OfficeUtilitiesRg))
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Inland Empire" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), OfficeUtilitiesRg) _
                            + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "cahied"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "cahrvr"), OfficeUtilitiesRg))
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta East" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), OfficeUtilitiesRg) _
                            + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atlse"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atle"), OfficeUtilitiesRg))
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta North" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), OfficeUtilitiesRg) _
                            + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atlnw"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atln"), OfficeUtilitiesRg))
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta South" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), OfficeUtilitiesRg) _
                            + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atlsw"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atls"), OfficeUtilitiesRg))
                        End If

                    Else
                        Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), OfficeUtilitiesRg)
                    End If

                Case "Office - Other ($)"
                    isItem = True

                    If r.End(xlUp) = "Tie-Out To Actuals" Or r.End(xlUp) = "Entity Level Assumptions" _
                    Or r.End(xlUp) = "Inland Empire" Or r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta East" _
                    Or r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta North" Or r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta South" Then

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Tie-Out To Actuals" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(OfficeOtherRg)
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Entity Level Assumptions" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(EntityGLRg(AllEntRg, OfficeOtherRg))
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Inland Empire" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), OfficeOtherRg) _
                            + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "cahied"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "cahrvr"), OfficeOtherRg))
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta East" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), OfficeOtherRg) _
                            + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atlse"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atle"), OfficeOtherRg))
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta North" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), OfficeOtherRg) _
                            + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atlnw"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atln"), OfficeOtherRg))
                        End If

                        If r.End(xlUp) = "Atlanta South" Then
                            Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), OfficeOtherRg) _
                            + Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atlsw"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atls"), OfficeOtherRg))
                        End If

                    Else
                        Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = SinglePMRanges(r.End(xlUp), OfficeOtherRg)
                    End If

                Case "Bad Debt ($)"
                    Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(CategoryGLRange("Bad Debt ($)"))

            End Select
        Next r
Set r = Nothing
End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

endtime = Now()

MsgBox (Format(endtime - starttime, "h:mm:ss"))


End Sub


Public Function DefMultiCCPMRange(rngSearchRange As Range, strSearchString As String) As Range
    If Not AllEntRg.Find(strSearchString, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
        Set DefMultiCCPMRange = rngSearchRange.Find(strSearchString, lookat:=xlWhole)
    End If
End Function

Public Function EntityGLRg(EntityRg1 As Range, CatGLRg As Range) As Range
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In EntityRg1
        If CCRg.Find(c.Value, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
            Dim c2 As Range
            For Each c2 In CatGLRg
                If c2.Row = c.Row Then
                    If EntityGLRg Is Nothing Then
                        Set EntityGLRg = c2
                    Else
                        Set EntityGLRg = Union(EntityGLRg, c2)
                    End If
                End If
            Next c2
        End If
    Next c
End Function

Public Function CategoryGLRange(TypeString As String) As Range
    Dim cl As Range
    For Each cl In TypeRg
        If cl = TypeString Then
            Dim TempCell As Range
            Set TempCell = GLRg.Find(cl.Offset(0, 1).Value, lookat:=xlWhole)

            If CategoryGLRange Is Nothing Then
                Set CategoryGLRange = Wk1.Range(Wk1.Cells(FRow, TempCell.Column), Wk1.Cells(lRow, TempCell.Column))
            Else
                Set CategoryGLRange = Union(CategoryGLRange, Wk1.Range(Wk1.Cells(FRow, TempCell.Column), Wk1.Cells(lRow, TempCell.Column)))
            End If
        End If
    Next cl
End Function

Public Function MultipleCostCenterGLRange(CostCenterRg1 As Range, CostCenterRg2 As Range, CatGLRg2 As Range) As Range
    If Not CostCenterRg1 Is Nothing Or Not CostCenterRg2 Is Nothing Then
        Dim cl2 As Range
        For Each cl2 In CatGLRg2
            If cl2.Row = CostCenterRg1.Row Or cl2.Row = CostCenterRg2.Row Then
                If MultipleCostCenterGLRange Is Nothing Then
                    Set MultipleCostCenterGLRange = cl2
                Else
                    Set MultipleCostCenterGLRange = Union(MultipleCostCenterGLRange, cl2)
                End If
            End If
        Next cl2
    End If
End Function

Public Function CCCodeCell(PMToCC As Range) As Range
    CCCodeRow = CLinkRg.Find(PMToCC.Value, lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(0, 1).Row
    CCCodeCol = CLinkRg.Find(PMToCC.Value, lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(0, 1).Column
    Set CCCodeCell = Wk5.Cells(CCCodeRow, CCCodeCol)
End Function

Public Function SinglePMRanges(PMCell As Range, GLCatRg As Range) As Double

Dim Col As Range
Dim MCol As Long
Dim MRow As Long

For Each Col In GLCatRg.Columns
    MCol = Col.Column

    Dim TotRg As Range
    Dim zz As Range
    For Each zz In OpsRg
      If zz = PMCell Then
          If TotRg Is Nothing Then
              Set TotRg = Wk1.Cells(zz.Row, MCol)
          Else
              Set TotRg = Union(TotRg, Wk1.Cells(zz.Row, MCol))
          End If
      End If
    Next zz

    Dim Tot2Rg As Range
    If CCCodeCell(PMCell).Value <> "None" Then
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(CLinkRg, PMCell) = 1 Then
            If Not DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, CCCodeCell(PMCell)) Is Nothing Then
              If Tot2Rg Is Nothing Then
                  Set Tot2Rg = Wk1.Cells(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, CCCodeCell(PMCell)).Row, MCol)
              Else
                  Set Tot2Rg = Union(Tot2Rg, Wk1.Cells(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, CCCodeCell(PMCell)).Row, MCol))
              End If
            End If
            SinglePMRanges = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(TotRg, Tot2Rg)
        Else
            SinglePMRanges = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(TotRg)
        End If
    Else
        'Do Nothing --- 3rd Party PM; No CostCenter Code to lookup and calculate GL amounts
        SinglePMRanges = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(TotRg)
    End If
Next Col

End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview, fonzy16.

Comment: Please state only the code's purpose in the title.  It's otherwise difficult to determine what the code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 5):

I like to start off by saying that your formatting is pretty good.  Well done.  But there are a few things to simplify your code and make it easier to understand.  From there it will be easier to manage and even improve the performance.

Also, the use of functions to solve smaller problems is good.

### Functions

Your comments about 'public functions' are a little vague.  Functions are used to improve the maintainability of code and ideally allow you to reuse the functionality in other places.  It doesn't add any performance (if anything calling a function decreases performance).

So for instance a common function I use is to find the last used row in a worksheet.  It serves a specific purpose, is only 5-10 lines long, but I use it all over the place when I'm coding.  The cool thing is that I can replace the way it works internally without affecting any of the consumers of that function.

The use of 'Public' (and also the alternative, Private) is to control who can access a function, variable, property.  In programming this is called [Scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29).  Basically when you make something Public you are telling other code that this function is for public use.

As I mentioned above, you should separate out logical chunks of code into separate functions.  Some of these functions may *not* be suitable for use outside of their module.  In this case they can be declared Private and they won't be visible outside that module.

### Use Variables for repeated code references

you have a huge number of `r.End(xlUp)` references in your code.  I suggest you figure out what this range represents and use a variable to name it appropriately.  Similarly with `Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4)`.  I have actually pulled these into a method which you will see below.

### Use of With Blocks

It appears you are not understanding how [`With` blocks work](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264723.aspx).  The reason I'm saying this is because I commented out all of the beginning and ending `With` statements and the code still compiles.  The purpose of these blocks is to reduce repetition of an object reference inside the containing code.  So for instance instead of writing a lot of statements like this `Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum( ... )` You can replace them with this:

```
With Application.WorksheetFunction
    ' Notice that we can leave out the Application.WorksheetFunction 
    ' part and just add a leading '.'
    .Sum( ... )
End With
```

### Code Duplication

There is a huge amount of duplication in your code.  Every time you use copy and paste you need to ask whether you are doing the right thing.  Quite often you can see a pattern in what you are doing and can create a separate method (`Function` or `Sub`) that can be created to solve that particular problem.  The things that are changing between uses of that code become your arguments/parameters.

Take for example the `Select Case` statement inside the main loop of `Maverick()`.  Each case has very similar code inside of it.  The only things that appear to be changing each time is the range that is used.  So you could create a new method which accepts a range argument and a reference to the output workbook (WK4 in this case) and performs the processing.  Somthing similar to the following:

```
' I have tried my best to factor out this method but I quite likely missed something,
' so carefully review this to make sure that nothing has been missed.
Private Function ProcessStuff(ByVal processRange As Range, ByVal currentRow As Range)
    ' Using With block to simplify calls to Sum().
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        ' The following two variables should be renamed to match the semantics of the data they represent.
        Dim entryType As Range
        entryType = currentRow.End(xlUp)

        Dim outputCell As Range
        Set outputCell = Wk4.Cells(currentRow.Row, 4)

        ' Using a select case statement instead of nested If hierarchy.
        Select Case entryType
            Case "Tie-Out To Actuals"
                outputCell = .Sum(processRange)

            Case "Entity Level Assumptions"
                outputCell = .Sum(EntityGLRg(AllEntRg, processRange))

            Case "Inland Empire"
                outputCell = SinglePMRanges(entryType, processRange) _
                + .Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "cahied"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "cahrvr"), processRange))

            Case "Atlanta East"
                outputCell = SinglePMRanges(entryType, processRange) _
                + .Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atlse"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atle"), processRange))

            Case "Atlanta North"
                outputCell = SinglePMRanges(entryType, processRange) _
                + .Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atlnw"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atln"), processRange))

            Case "Atlanta South"
                outputCell = SinglePMRanges(entryType, processRange) _
                + .Sum(MultipleCostCenterGLRange(DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atlsw"), DefMultiCCPMRange(AllEntRg, "atls"), processRange))

            Case Else
                outputCell = SinglePMRanges(entryType, processRange)
        End Select
    End With
End Function
```

Then your loop code simplifies down to:

```
Dim r As Range
Dim isItem As Boolean
    For Each r In AssumptionRg

        Select Case r
            Case "Evictions ($)"
                isItem = True
                ProcessStuff EvictionRg, r

            Case "Credit Verification Fees ($)"
                isItem = True
                ProcessStuff CreditFeesRg, r

            Case "Legal Counsel Fees ($)"
                isItem = True
                ProcessStuff LegalCounselFeesRg, r

            Case "Office - Prop Mgmt ($)"
                isItem = True
                ProcessStuff OfficeMgmtRg, r

            Case "Office - Rent ($)"
                isItem = True
                ProcessStuff OfficeRentRg, r

            Case "Office - Utilities ($)"
                isItem = True
                ProcessStuff OfficeUtilitiesRg, r

            Case "Office - Other ($)"
                isItem = True
                ProcessStuff OfficeOtherRg, r

            Case "Bad Debt ($)"
                Wk4.Cells(r.Row, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(CategoryGLRange("Bad Debt ($)"))

        End Select
    Next r
```

If you end up using this code, please carefully check it.

Comment: @Rossco...Thanks for the detailed input.  I just got out of morning meetings otherwise I would have responded sooner.  I appreciate the insight.  Everything you mentioned makes sense.  I will look at your suggestion and see how I can apply it and test the results.  Also, I will use try to apply that concept to consolidate to other portions of the code.  Hopefully it reduces the execution time.  I will let you know of the results